# How to enforce api to accept json in spark java

Tags: java, rest, spark-java

There is a method which takes acceptType(Content-Type) but accepts any content type when "application/json" is passed.

```
public static void post(String path, String acceptType, Route route)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to enforce api to accept json in spark java

This can't be done. The method you're using only routes requests based on headers, it doesn't inspect the actual content.